# Open a URL in a new tab of active window in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, safari-extension

Can't get the variable `safari` from safari console, raises the following error: can't find variable: safari

```
var newTab = safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab();
newTab.url = "http://something"
```

Answer (score 2):

This needs to be done in the context of a global background page, rather than in the context of an actual open page.

In the Extension Builder, ensure you have a global page set, and click the "Inspect Global Page" button. In that console the following will work:

```
var newtab = safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.openTab();
newtab.url = 'http://www.google.com';
```

See the Apple Safari Extensions Development guide for more information on global pages and injected scripts, and how you can communicate between them with messages:

- [Adding a Global HTML Page](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/AddingaGlobalHTMLPage/AddingaGlobalHTMLPage.html)
- [Injecting Scripts](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/InjectingScripts/InjectingScripts.html)
- [Messages and Proxies](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/MessagesandProxies/MessagesandProxies.html)